# Azure DevOps - How to use new rollup columns

Tags: azure-devops

I noticed in the Azure DevOps release notes for the sprint 157 new feature - [Track the progress of parent items using Rollup on Boards backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-157-update#track-the-progress-of-parent-items-using-rollup-on-boards-backlog).

The problem is that I don't see such columns in my backlog and I don't see any option to add them. What I can do to enable this feature for my backlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is you're not on Sprint 157 yet. Looking at all the DevOps environments I have access to, none of them are on 157 yet. I based this on the fact that the "What's new" on the bottom left still shows Sprint 156.

Taken from the [Sprint 157 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-157-update):

> **Note**
>   These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks.

Comment: That's weird, because "What's new" in my case shows Sprint 157. Anyway, I didn't notice the info that these features will roll out over the next 2-3 weeks, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Per my conversation with the Feature Team, 
“Rollup is still rolling out. Unfortunately we experienced some issues that delayed the release but they were all fixed now and should be rolling out gradually. 
Sorry for any inconvenience.”

Answer (score 0):

We are supposed to have Sprint 157, but no rollup board columns yet.

[image: Screenshot sprint 157]